# Many to many relational hierarchy across 3 entities

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many, hierarchical-data

I have a requirement as below,
there are three entities, let's say, Entity 1 (E1), Entity 2(E2), Entity 3(E3) (the attributes of all three entities have same attributes except for Entity 1 which only has a subset of the complete attribute set)

The relationship goes this way,

1. E1 can be linked to another E1
2. E1 can have one or more E2
3. E1 can have one or more E3
4. E2/E3 can be associated to multiple E1
5. E2 can be linked to another E2
6. E2 can have one or more E3
7. E3 can be associated to multiple E2

*(E3 cannot be linked to another E3)

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUDdW.jpg)

As they have similar attribute, the design of tables i could possibly think of, is to have a table with ID and TYPE (which says it is E1/E2/E3). Then, a link table which will just have PARENTID and CHILDID.

But as E1 has only a subset of attributes which the other entities have, I feel there is a de-normalization in this approach. We will be storing millions of records (if it's in one table for all three entities). Is there a better normalized and performance efficient approach?

SQL server version : Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I would say even if all attributes are same, its good to maintain 3 different tables and have a junction table which represent relationship between E1, E2 and E3. This way, its easy to extend the tables to accommodate changes to entities independently in future.

Comment: I'm reminded of the saying "A picture paints a thousand words."  Do you have an entity-relationship diagram of this?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you intend to use? Possible recommendations might depend on it (for example, graphs first appeared in 2017).

Comment: @STLDev, you're right. But I don't have a good tool to make an ERD. I tried my best.

Comment: @RogerWolf, I have updated SQL server version